# Dynamically creating Sub-Users in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I currently have admin users which have a email password login using firebase auth. These admin users have read and write access as set in security rules. I want to give the admin the ability to dynamically create subusers with limited access i.e with only read access for a certain node in firebase database. This node is not public accessible, I want to limit it to this admin and it's subusers.

**My thought** : is to generate secondary users username and password myself.  And use that to do a basic custom Auth using firebase functions and add custom claims such as Admins `UID` so I can use that for security rules to give read permission for the Admin Node Only and another `{sub-user: true}` claim to the client to render subuser ui instead of the Admin UI.

If there is another method to achieve creating sub-accounts more efficiently, please suggest so.

Comment: How do you plan to have the admin user create accounts? using the Firebase client SDK or Admin SDK?

Comment: trigger a cloud-function that creates a new `user` using the username and password and save those creds in the database. Then the admin will provide the creds to the subuser. Issue i'm running into now is that custom claims need a `UID`

Comment: Provisioning a user account by storing the password in the database when it is already hashed and salted by the Auth backend and then passing it to the user is a really bad idea. It is against authentication best practices.